# How can I display the files pulled in from S3 on my frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, amazon-s3, multer

I have an image that was uploaded to S3 and I am now attempting to get the file stream and display the image on my frontend. I appear to have successfully accessed the image in my backend but keep having difficulties getting it to display on my frontend.

Functions to get the file from S3:

```
    getFileStream: function getFileStream(fileKey){
        const downloadParams ={
            Key: fileKey,
            Bucket: bucketName
        }
        return s3.getObject(downloadParams).createReadStream();
    }
```

Post route uploading the image to S3 and implementing res.send to give the file a path on download:

```
router.post('/admin/create', upload.single('images'), async(req, res) => {
    try{
        const file = req.file;
        console.log(req.file);
        const result = await uploadFile(file);
        await unlinkFile(file.path);
        console.log(result);
        const newItem = await db.query("INSERT INTO collection (title, product, imagekey, price, info) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *", [req.body.title, req.body.product, result.key, req.body.price, req.body.info]);
        res.send({imagePath: `/images/${result.key}`})
        res.status(201).json({
            status: "success",
            results: newItem.rows.length,
            data:{
                newItem: newItem.rows[0]
            }
        })
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

Get route for the image:

```
router.get("/images/:key", async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const key = req.params.key;
        const readStream = getFileStream(key);
        readStream.pipe(res);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

The image key of every file uploaded is stored within my database along with the rest of the image's data. I created a function in my front end to map the correct "src" to every image so that the image would be displayed. ("/images/${imagekey}")

```
    const imageURL = (imagekey) =>{
        return(`/images/${imagekey}`);
    }
```

```
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="main-body">
                <div className="collection-menu">
                    {collection && collection.map(item => {
                        return(
                                <div className="collection-item">
                                    <ImagesC classes="collection-thumbnail" source={imageURL(item.imagekey)}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

My image component:

```
const ImagesC = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <img className={props.classes} src={props.source}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't your `imageURL` function look for images locally?

Comment: @KiprasT The imageURL function is called within the mapped template and takes in a parameter of the image key that was save in my database when the file was first uploaded to S3. This function is simply meant to add the correct src address to every image element. (ie. "/images/{imagekey}